# TYPO3 Plugin: ways to insert on a page

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to insert a frontend plugin to a page without having a template (and markers) included?

Normally I use:

```
10.marks {
    CONTENT_LEFT < plugin.tx_xy_p1
}
```

But in a new project I dont want to have a template file where the markers (`###CONTENT_LEFT###`) are included. The plugin should appear as the only thing on that page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want is the plugin, simply create a sparkingly fresh root template with the standard page object of type PAGE, and insert plugin content there.

Create a new page with rootflag etc, and maybe the static files for your plugin, if needed. In the setup field enter your adaption of this:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 < plugin.tt_news
```

You might of course need to add more, depending on your needs, but this should be the principle (and it works, I tested just now). :-)