# ExtBase Detail View in Lightbox

Tags: typo3, magnific-popup, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-6.2.x

I made an Extension with Extbase and iwant the detail view to be shown in a lightbox and it does. The Problem is: I dont want the main template (of the main page with navigation etc.) to be seen, but just the detailed view. What do I have to change, to exclude the Main Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dedicated `typeNum` for this content and in its TS configuration set: `disableAllHeaderCode = 1`, it can be compared to the common way of rendering pure AJAX types like showed in [the other sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21885324/1066240).

For an example put this into your TypoScript template

```
myPurePage = PAGE
myPurePage {
  typeNum = 1234

  10 < styles.content.get  

  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
  }

}
```

So if you'll call it by `http://yourdomain.tld/?id=123&type=1234` it will show only content of the **main column** from page with UID `123` (without `html`, `body` sections, any navigations from default template, etc, etc)

Comment: Ok, im relatively new at typo3, especially typoscript. Where exactly do i put this code?

Comment: Into your main TypoScript Template, additionally you need to modify your extension to add this `1234` (or other of your choice) to the url as a `type` param, i.e. `&type=1234`

Comment: Okay, it works, how you said. But it is not quite what i need. I even tried making a new template just for this view and that didnt work either, i just get no content at all (cant really figure out why, the data should be in the link, to find all information)

Comment: I gave you simple sample how to use alternative behaviour using typeNum, you don't need to disable header code, for an example you can... just replace the ... template file

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the solution @biesior provided: Use the extension [typoscript_rendering](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/typoscript_rendering). It provides a [ViewHelper](https://github.com/helhum/typoscript_rendering/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/Uri/AjaxActionViewHelper.php) to generate a link that renders only the view for an extbase action, without the layout.